# WIX project generator for Visual Studio Code

Tags: wix

Is there a way to create wix project on vscode? I read their site but no hit. I've already installed wix, but i dont have visual studio, only vscode

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer
[here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781784393212/1/ch01lvl1sec13/building-a-wix-installer-from-the-command-line)
using wix cli